# Change logging level for all Connexion loggers at once

Tags: python, logging, connexion, structlog

Is there a way to stop or reduce logging?

You can either

- limit all application logging to certain level (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ...) - that's to broad and not suitable
- limit concrete connexion loggers (ie. `connexion.operations.abstract`) to certein level - that's too narrow and connexion has lot of different loggers, which can be good for development of connexion itself, but is nuisance otherways

  - this way I've managed to create list of many `connexion.*` loggers and reduce logging to some amount (using `structlog.get_logger(logger_name).setLevel(logging.WARNING)`), but there are still some huge logs on DEBUG level that starts with

    - `Attaching x-scope to {`
    - `Ref #/components/`
    - `Dereferencing {`

Is there some way to get rid of these logs? Or even better select logger via wildcard somehow? ie `connexion.*`?

Thanks for answer.

Michal

PS: Asked same question on Connexion Github: https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/1417

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `connexion` doesn't use structlog so setting the level on concrete loggers won't do you much good.

You're gonna have to use stdlib's global configuration. Something like:

```
[loggers]
keys = root, connexion, ...

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stdout,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(message)s

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_connexion]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = connexion
```

Which you then load using `logging.config.fileConfig()`